# Make DataContext continue to insert if errors occur

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm working with a `DataContext` object and Linq to SQL in c#. I'm attempting to transfer the votes for a wish on a wishlist to a question that the administrator has determined that the first question is a duplicate of. However, since the `vote` table has the `WishId` and `UserId` as primary keys, if the user has already voted on the destination wish, then the insert will fail. What I would like to do is ignore these cases (without querying the `vote` table before inserting) and insert all the valid votes. This is what I would like to do.

```
using (linqWishesDataContext dataContext = new linqWishesDataContext())
{
    try
    {
        dataContext.WishlistUpvotes.InsertAllOnSubmit(destinationVotes);
        dataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
    }
    catch{}
}
```

One solution I have right now is to do this:

```
foreach (WishlistUpvote vote in destinationVotes)
{
    using (linqWishesDataContext dataContext = new linqWishesDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            dataContext.WishlistUpvotes.InsertOnSubmit(vote);
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

But if there are a couple hundred or a couple thousand votes that need moved then it seems like a bad idea to create a new `DataContext` for each vote. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a new `DataContext` each time; you can reuse the same one, and simply loop your calls as you are now, otherwise.

```
using (linqWishesDataContext dataContext = new linqWishesDataContext())
{
    foreach (WishlistUpvote vote in destinationVotes)
    {
        try
        {
            dataContext.WishlistUpvotes.InsertOnSubmit(vote);
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Of course, this will issue individual commands for each update. (though ADO.NET connection pooling will still be working behind the scenes, so it's not *that* horrible) Without manually building the SQL for inserts, I don't know what else you could do. The data context will do all changes for one call to `SubmitChanges()` in a transaction, which is why you get the 'all or nothing' behavior.